# Need a generic way to extract error text

Tags: ios, nserror

I've developed some `iOS 6.1` code to deal with `NSError`.  But, I'm not happy with it.  It is at best a hack:

```
 -(bool) reptErrAtModule: (NSString *) module
                  atSubr: (NSString *) subr
                  atFunc: (NSString *) func
                 withErr: (NSError *) err
   {
   id value = [[err userInfo] objectForKey: NSUnderlyingErrorKey];
   NSString * errDesc = (value != nil) ? 
                        [value localizedDescription]:
                        (NSString *)[[err userInfo] objectForKey: @"reason"];

   NSLog( @"ERR -> %@",[NSString stringWithFormat: 
          @"(%@>%@) %@ failed! %@",module,subr,func,errDesc] );
   }
```

I had a simpler form (without the `(NSString *)[[err userInfo] objectForKey: @"reason"]` case) and it worked for errors that I got back from calls to `removeItemAtPath`.

But then I got an error back from this code:

```
NSPersistentStore * entStor = 
 [myPerStoCor addPersistentStoreWithType: NSSQLiteStoreType
                           configuration: nil
                                     URL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: Path]
                                 options: nil
                                   error: &err];
```

And my routine failed to extract the error.  So I added the `@"reason"` logic because I could see the text I wanted in the Info data in the debugger.

Now the code works with both types of errors but I'm thinking this is not the way to do this.  There must be a better, more generic way to deal with all the types of errors stuff the system can give you back in `NSError`.

Comment: Is your goal here to present the error to the user or log it out for debugging/troubleshooting purposes?

Comment: Mike, probably both.  Right now, during development, I am primarily dropping messages for myself via NSLog but later, I might want to present some of this information to the user in a nicer format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this:

```
NSString *description = error.localizedDescription;
NSString *reason = error.localizedFailureReason;
NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", description, reason];
```

Comment: And does this work for all the errors that arise for you or do you sometimes get a NULL back for the reason?

Comment: Well, this bit of code is inside a util method: + (UIAlertView *) alertViewWithError:(NSError *)error .... and I always have a message in the alert view, so yes it works for all of my errors. Whether there are cases where it doesn't work, I don't know.

Comment: When I set the removeItemAtPath code up to fail and return me data in NSError, I get "(Cocoa error 4.) (null)" with your method and "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory" with mine.  In this case,  I prefer mine.

Comment: I think I'm going to re-ask this question because I'm still looking for something more generic.

Comment: @Gallymon It seems you already have all the pieces yourself that you can put together to make a nice method to do what you require.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, you ideally want to log out the entire contents of the error. Roughly speaking this is the `domain`, `code`, and `userInfo`. Bear in mind that `userInfo` might well include an underlying error, which you want to apply the same logic to. And in some cases, the error might supply a description (or failure reason etc.) which [isn't present in the `userInfo`](http://www.mikeabdullah.net/error-synthesis-cheatsheet.html).

If you scroll down my blog post at http://www.mikeabdullah.net/easier-core-data-error-debugging.html, there's a snippet there showing how to generate a dictionary representation of an `NSError` object, and then get a string representation of that. This is pretty handy for debugging/logging purposes.

For presentation to users though, `-[NSError localizedDescription]` is expressly designed for such purposes. `-localizedFailureReason` serves a similar role, tending to specify what went wrong, without the context of the operation being tried. (One way to think of it is `localizedDescription = task desceription + localizedFailureReason`)